# Working with BigQuery Connector through Service Account in WSO2 EI 6.5.0

Tags: google-bigquery, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am using [BigQuery Connector](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/connectors/bigquery-connector/bigquery-connector-reference/) in WSo2 EI 6.5.0 to work with Dataset, Tables etc.

In my case, I need to generate credentials through Service Account.

- In `bigquery.init` Operation there is `apiKey` param is there. It needs to be known whether API key alone is sufficient for this integration?
- If Oauth2 parameters are needed, then creation of those credentials through Service Account instead of individual IDs. how can we do this?

Kindly clarify on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either an API Key or OAuth parameters. You don't need both. For Oauth Application creation you can take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) document.

Comment: Hi @ycr,
Thanks for clarification and sharing ref link. I believe BigQuery does not support API Key authorization. It is possible to utilize an OAuth-based approach.